# regexp for mysql 5.1 (look up entry based on user input)

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-5.1

How do I write a regular expression which checks for entries that contain within them, a specific character pattern input by the user. For instance,

User input: `at`
Desired return: `cat,at,atom,distillate,`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%at%'
```

Comment: ...note that, you probably want to filter user input to something like [a-z0-9] before plugging it into a wildcard to avoid things like `'; DROP TABLE users; --` being entered into your string. Building a wildcard from user input is moderately risky behaviour. Also... you asked about regular expressions... while MySQL has a `REGEXP` keyword, the `LIKE` patterns are generally much faster and are more portable SQL expressions, albeit only useful in simple cases like this.